# How to make a presence lookup with UCMA

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

I'm having a LocalOwnerPresence object, which I want to get the PresenceState object of, to compute against another PresenceState to check if they are equals.
Does anyone knows where the PresenceState of a LocalOwnerPresence is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LocalOwnerPresence is part of the endpoint (either Application or User).

To retrieve presence for the local endpoint, you can use

_endpoint.LocalOwnerPresence.[BeginSubscribe()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.presence.publishsubscribesession.beginsubscribe%28v=office.13%29.aspx)

Before doing this though, you should make sure you subscribe to the [PresenceNotificationReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.presence.remotepresenceview.presencenotificationreceived_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx) event handler so that you can receive events.